# Which one is good mongodb aggregate or mongodb functions

Tags: mongodb, function, compare, aggregation

Which one is good mongodb **aggregate** or mongodb **functions**

what i mean to say : mongodb aggregation or mongodb functional which one is preforable and which one gives good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb functions

> Defines a custom aggregation function or expression in JavaScript.

Whereas aggregation is a prebuilt supported operations.

> Executing JavaScript inside an aggregation expression may decrease performance. Only use the $function operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application's needs.

If you have a logic which needs to be customised not supported out of the box, go for functions.

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/)

Comment: If that was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark